# Strange Low-Quality Review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

[Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5122337)

- The whole question where this answer was got deleted 5 years ago. How can it enter the queue at all? (aren't the only flags for moderator attention?)
- It was no audit.
- The text is so low quality that there is no doubt at all
- And on top of that, it's *community wiki* (Turtles, seriously?)

Can someone explain to me how this is possible, or if I found another bug in the reviews?

Comment: Now that my curiosity is piqued, I want to see this post. Oh well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The question was originally migrated to Meta Stack Exchange. Just recently, it got deleted there. This caused the migration to be rejected (and reversed). There's currently a bug(?) where rejected migrations undelete all the answers on the original site, even if the question there has since been deleted (which is almost always if it's been over 90 days). That means there were a bunch of undeleted answers on a deleted question. Since that one was such low quality, the system picked it up and threw it into the review queue.

After a while, the system eventually deletes all the answers again and invalidates all the review items.

Comment: Isn't the auto-delete timer on migration sources 30 days?