# Strange thing during late-answer review

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, deleted-questions

Looks similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261282/strange-low-quality-review), but it happened during late answer review (like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267422/late-answer-and-deleted-question-review-audit) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267648/question-not-found-on-audit-possible-bug?cb=1), the [answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263155/answers-to-deleted-questions-are-still-being-used-in-review-audits/265278#265278) says that this should be fixed).

I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5570254) to review. It appeared only as answer with 0 rep, no comments and as posted 2 hours ago (and no question below the answer). When I followed a link to that answer, I found that question was removed (by the author), so I chose "No action needed" as "I'm done" is disabled and I can't see deleted posts (and I can't do anything to enable "I'm done"). And then I got "This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass."

What should I choose for such cases? The only other option is just to skip that and for me "No action needed" is viable option in this case as all needed actions are already taken and no additional ones needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations! You've passed 500 reputation, so you've gained [the ability](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) to review [First Posts](//stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [Late Answers](//stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers).

In these review queues, it is your job to take a look at new users' posts and decide how to act on them. However, some people get lazy with their reviewing and like to go through the review queues very quickly, making rash decisions in an attempt to get badges for review actions more easily.

To combat these "robo-reviewers," as they're called, we have an [audit system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) in place to make sure that people are paying attention when they're reviewing posts. If you fail too many of these audits, you'll be banned from reviewing for a while.

Audits are chosen by the system: the reason why the supposed answerer had only 1 reputation and the answer had no votes is because the usercard is anonymized and the post score is not shown to prevent bias from influencing your review actions.

In this case, the answer you were reviewing was to a deleted question (as you've noticed), so that should tip you off that it's 1) an audit and 2) probably not a great answer. Let's look at the post you were reviewing:

> Simply create a Dictionary between Char and custom class ArrayList, in this class put any data you love , char , int or collections

First of all, that is not an answer to the question, but you may not have known that since you could not see the question. However, since we know that it's an audit, you should be able to guess what kind of action the system wants you to take to pass the audit: negative (it's not a particularly spectacular post). You should have downvoted, commented, edited, or flagged the answer, all of which would have triggered an audit pass in this case. It is most certainly *not* **No Action Needed**.

If you're looking for a more detailed explanation of audits, I would look at the FAQ I've linked to above and [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266105/failed-audit-review-but-the-counter-went-up/266108#266108) that I wrote for new reviewers.

Comment: I understand that most appropriate would be to comment/edit, but I couldn't do it(or, at least, didn't notice how to do it with that post) because question was already deleted(and so was the answer). And only options left were "No action needed" and "Skip". I guess audit would be failed anyway. And as all measures were taken already, those two options look similar for me.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov Ah, I see what you're saying: so you couldn't take any action on the post because it was deleted?

Comment: Yes, that's right. After looking around for some time I've found that I could post comment right from review(which I didn't notice; I think I've used such thing once, but didn't pay attention).

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov Yes, the First Posts/Late Answer queues are quite open-ended because they want you to get used to reviewing and do as much as you can to help new users.